# how to show a particular slide in a slider based on the requested URL using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `Register` button on the page, by clicking on it Jquery takes the control down to last slide using the code below

```
   $(".register").on("click", function (e) {
    if (!IsMobile()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!ScrollAnimating()) {
            $('.home-nav ul li').removeClass('active');
            $('.home-nav ul li:nth-child(6)').addClass('active');
            SnapScroll("6", 3000);
        }
    }
});
```

I want to put an anchor tag in a URL like http://www.somesite.com/#Register and if the URL contains this anchor tag `#Register` I want to execute the same code i.e. jump to the last slide.

I tried putting a hidden anchor just before the sixth slide like below but the jump to the section is not the same and we get by calling `SnapScroll("6", 3000);`

```
 <a id="Register" style="visibility: hidden"></a>
   <section class="sc6 slide">
    ......
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(window.location.hash == '#Register'){
    //do stuff
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?