# How to redirect to a particular slide in a slider on a page from an external link..?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to redirect to a particular slide in a landing page from a button in a external HTML page. I am able to redirect to a particular section from an URL using the #ID, but here i want to reach a section and open a slide inside this section by reading the URL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show some of your code or Trying adding a FIDDLE.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for responding,
I don't have a code, i just add the #ID of my element to the URL like this (http://www.somesite.com/#section_4). So this URL is directing me to this section_4 element but i wanna open up a particular slider number inside this section.

Comment: You can do this with a query string.  Add the slide ID (or something) to the URL query, and then retrieve it and use it as a variable on the target page.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer.

I tried this code,

```
if(window.location.hash == '#Register'){
    //do stuff
}
```

Ref: [how to show a particular slide in a slider based on the requested URL using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30485158/how-to-show-a-particular-slide-in-a-slider-based-on-the-requested-url-using-jque)

it read the #ID in the URL.
Thanks.